# Computing the integral $ \int \mathrm{d}x / [ (1 + \sqrt{x}) (x+1)^2]$

Tags: integration

I was looking around, and stumbled accross the fact that

$$
   \int \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(1+\sqrt{u})(1+u)^2\,} 
   = 
   \frac{1}{2} \kappa \left( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}\,} \right) 
   - 
   \frac{1}{4} \log\left( 1 + 2\kappa \right) 
$$
Where $\kappa = \sqrt{u}/(1+u)$

I know I have seen this integral before, but can not forthe life of me remember where. Are there any clever substitutions one can make, because partial fractions makes this a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Try $1+\sqrt{u} = t$ it will give easier transformation.
If you can't then leave a message I'll do completely.

Comment: You still end up with three integrals that magically end up canceling each other out at the end of the computation. Is there really nothing simpler than partial fractions?

Comment: actually i don't know how to write mathematical expression here that's why i'm giving hint.ok i'll try my way hope u can understand.